# UWP Bluetooth RFCOMM FindAllAsync

Tags: bluetooth, uwp, rfcomm, windowsiot

I want to build two simple apps, communicating with each other using Bluetooth RFCOMM.

However, when I run client app it doesn't find any devices with `_devices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(RfcommDeviceService.GetDeviceSelector(RfcommServiceId.ObexObjectPush));`

_devices collection  is empty.

Based on the examples from microsoft docs I've managed to write something like this.

Application receiving messages (server) - deployed on Raspberry PI 3.

```
namespace RaspRFCOMM
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        private RfcommServiceProvider _provider;

        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            this.Initialize();
        }

        private async void Initialize()
        {
            msgStatus.Text = "Inicjalizacja...";

            // Initialize the provider for the hosted RFCOMM service
            _provider = await RfcommServiceProvider.CreateAsync(RfcommServiceId.ObexObjectPush);

            // Create a listener for this service and start listening
            StreamSocketListener listener = new StreamSocketListener();
            listener.ConnectionReceived += OnConnectionReceived;
            await listener.BindServiceNameAsync(
                _provider.ServiceId.AsString(),
                SocketProtectionLevel
                    .BluetoothEncryptionAllowNullAuthentication);

            // Set the SDP attributes and start advertising
            InitializeServiceSdpAttributes(_provider);
            _provider.StartAdvertising(listener, true);
        }

        const uint SERVICE_VERSION_ATTRIBUTE_ID = 0x0300;
        const byte SERVICE_VERSION_ATTRIBUTE_TYPE = 0x0A;   // UINT32
        const uint SERVICE_VERSION = 200;
        private void InitializeServiceSdpAttributes(RfcommServiceProvider provider)
        {
            DataWriter writer = new DataWriter();

            // First write the attribute type
            writer.WriteByte(SERVICE_VERSION_ATTRIBUTE_TYPE);
            // Then write the data
            writer.WriteUInt32(SERVICE_VERSION);

            IBuffer data = writer.DetachBuffer();
            provider.SdpRawAttributes.Add(SERVICE_VERSION_ATTRIBUTE_ID, data);
        }

        private async void OnConnectionReceived(
            StreamSocketListener listener,
            StreamSocketListenerConnectionReceivedEventArgs args)
        {
            msgStatus.Text = "Odczytuje...";

            _provider.StopAdvertising();
            listener.Dispose();

            StreamSocket _socket = args.Socket;
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(_socket.InputStream.AsStreamForRead());

            string response = await reader.ReadLineAsync();
            msgStatus.Text = "Odczytałem...";
            textboxMsg.Text = response + "To odczytalem";

        }
    }
}
```

Sending messages:

```
namespace WinRFCOMM
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        private RfcommDeviceService _service;
        private StreamSocket _socket;
        private DeviceInformationCollection _devices;
        private StreamWriter _writer;

        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            this.Initialize();
        }

        private async void Initialize()
        {
            msgStatus.Text = "Inicjalizacja...";
            _devices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(RfcommDeviceService.GetDeviceSelector(RfcommServiceId.ObexObjectPush));

            this.PopulateDevicesListview(_devices);
            msgStatus.Text = "Oczekiwanie na wybór...";
        }

        private void PopulateDevicesListview(DeviceInformationCollection devices)
        {
            foreach (DeviceInformation di in devices)
            {
                String deviceInfo = di.Name + " - " + di.Id;
                lvDevices.Items.Add(deviceInfo);
            }
        }

        private void btnConnect_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var selected = lvDevices.SelectedIndex;
            if (selected != -1)
            {
                ConnectToRFC(_devices[selected]);
            }
        }

        private async void ConnectToRFC(DeviceInformation selectedDevice)
        {
            _service = await RfcommDeviceService.FromIdAsync(selectedDevice.Id);

            _socket = new StreamSocket();

            await _socket.ConnectAsync(
                _service.ConnectionHostName,
                _service.ConnectionServiceName,
                SocketProtectionLevel
                    .BluetoothEncryptionAllowNullAuthentication);

            msgStatus.Text = "Połączono...";

            _writer = new StreamWriter(_socket.OutputStream.AsStreamForWrite());
            _writer.WriteLineAsync("Test");
        }
    }
}
```

Both have manifest file set up like this:

```
  <Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="internetClient" />
    <Capability Name="internetClientServer" />
    <Capability Name="privateNetworkClientServer" />
    <DeviceCapability Name="bluetooth" />
  </Capabilities>
```

I'd really appreciate any help, because I've been stuck for almost 2 days.

Comment: Somehow it started to work, but I'm not sure why. I'll let know when I'll figure this out.

Comment: Can it work without pairing ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not reside in the code.

You need pair two devices firstly before running this RFCOMM sample. Because

> Use the RfcommDeviceService.GetDeviceSelector* functions to help
>   generate an AQS query that can be used to enumerated paired device
>   instances of the desired service.

Ref: [Send a file as a client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/send-or-receive-files-with-rfcomm#send-a-file-as-a-client)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however pairing devices does not solve the problem yet. Listing devices with RfcommServiceId.ObexObjectPush selector still doesn't work. It show raspberry device with BluetoothDevice.GetDeviceSelector(), but then it throws the "Element can not be found" exception on RfcommDeviceService.FromIdAsync().

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4760a2a4-9133-4658-9f18-c5aae2b39341/bluetooth-rfcomm-socketstreamconnectasynchostnamestring-systemexception-element-not-found?forum=winappswithcsharp) forum post which got me through it.

My problem was trying to use the DeviceInformation I had discovered for pairing, as my point of connection for RFCOMM.

For rfcomm you will require your AppManifest to look like:

```
 <DeviceCapability Name="bluetooth.rfcomm">

  <Device Id="any">

   <Function Type ="name:serialPort"/>

  </Device>  

</DeviceCapability>
```

Instead of just having the name "bluetooth".